# How to seperate catalina.out file regarding the application

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, catalina

I wonder if it is possible to seperate catalina.out file regarding the application in Linux. i.e. I have two different webapps running under same tomcat. Both may have some unhandled exception logging. I want to have two different catalina.out file for each like catalina_webapp1.out and catalina_webapp2.out.

Comment: Look at the "swallowOutput" setting on the Context element?
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly well